# Is there a way to activate Network Tablet on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, 13.10, input-devices

I have the android app called GfxTablet and I only have one program (GIMP) that the app can give input on GIMP. Based on the site [1], it says that can work with any Linux program on the computer.  But I don't know how to get into the Network Tablet settings on other programs or a global setting for it.  Is there a way to do it?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit and a Nexus 7 2013.  Both devices have GfxTablet successfully installed.

[1]http://rfc2822.github.io/GfxTablet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me as an additional mouse, but it has the problem that without the Stylus or a device that can detect hovering it acts (outside of gimp) as if the mouse is clicked all the time, and that confuses most applications.

Probably it is simply a matter of waiting for upgrades. I proposed one here: https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet/issues/50

About configuration: it shows up in Xubuntu configuration under "Mouse and touchpad" while the "./networktablet" driver is running:

[image: Network Tablet]

I checked under Gnome Shell on another PC and I found no way to find the additional settings. You know, this new fad of simplification versus configurability.

Probably it is simply a matter of waiting for upgrades. I proposed one here: https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet/issues/50

BTW, great app nonetheless. It has big potential.

Comment: I see.  And you have Xubuntu, Ubuntu doesn't have a way to see the settings for other mouse-like devices.  Is there a way to get to that?